# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (6,)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
train_auc = []
cv_auc = []
alpha_values = [1,2,3,4,5,10]
for alpha in alpha_values: 
    model = MultinomialNB(alpha = alpha)
    model.fit(X_tr_bow,Y_train) 
    y_tr_prob = batch_predict(model,X_tr_bow)    
    y_cr_prob =batch_predict(model, X_cr_bow)    
    train_auc.append(roc_auc_score(Y_train,y_tr_prob))
    cv_auc.append(roc_auc_score(Y_cv,y_cr_prob))
plt.plot(alpha, train_auc, label='Train AUC')
plt.plot(alpha, cv_auc, label='CV AUC')
plt.scatter(alpha, train_auc, label='Train AUC points')
plt.scatter(alpha, cv_auc, label='CV AUC points')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("alpha: hyperparameter")
plt.ylabel("roc_AUC_score")
plt.title("Roc_Auc score PLOTS")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

this code shows error x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (6,)

Comment: yes, alpha is one item, use alpha_values instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are plotting a single value `alpha` with your y-values which are lists. You need to use the complete x values. Replace `alpha` with `alpha_values` in all your plotting commands as following

```
plt.plot(alpha_values, train_auc, label='Train AUC')
plt.plot(alpha_values, cv_auc, label='CV AUC')
plt.scatter(alpha_values, train_auc, label='Train AUC points')
plt.scatter(alpha_values, cv_auc, label='CV AUC points')
```