# I can't fix this matplotlib error for graphing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried making some code that could graph a quadratic function but matplotlib kept giving me this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (11,) and (0,)
Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y =[]
for i in y:
    x = -5
    while x >= -5 and x <= 5:
        i = ((2*x**2) + (3*x) + 5)
        x += 1
plt.plot([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The for-loop doesn't make sense. Remove it and keep only the code in the loop. Each calculated value `i` must be appended to `y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (6,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527118/x-and-y-must-have-same-first-dimension-but-have-shapes-1-and-6)

Answer (score 0):

You `for` loop is useless, it never runs as `y` is initially empty.

Your code should have been:

```
y = []
x = -5
while x >= -5 and x <= 5:
    i = ((2*x**2) + (3*x) + 5)
    y.append(i)
    x += 1
plt.plot([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y)
```

Or:

```
x = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = []

for i in x:
    y.append(((2*i**2) + (3*i) + 5))

plt.plot(x, y)
```

But a better approach is to use a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = ((2*x**2) + (3*x) + 5)

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Output:

[image]